# Bash extract string

Tags: bash

Is there a way to extract this string? `libtirpc-common:arm64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1+deb11u1), libtirpc3:arm64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1+deb11u1), libtirpc-dev:arm64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1+deb11u1)`

I just want to get `libtirpc-common:arm64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1+deb11u1)`.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: How do you determine what to extract? The first comma-separated element? The element containing `common`?

Comment: It should be separated after the comma after the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -F '),' '{ printf "%s)",$1 }' <<< "libtirpc-common:arm64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1+deb11u1), libtirpc3:arm64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1+deb11u1), libtirpc-dev:arm64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1+deb11u1)"
```

Set the field separator to ")," and then print the first field followed by the )

Answer (score 0):

You could use `read` with a closing parenthesis delimiter (`-d')'`):

```bash
$ read -d')' extracted <<<'libtirpc-common:arm64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1+deb11u1), libtirpc3:arm64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1+deb11u1), libtirpc-dev:arm64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1+deb11u1)'
$
$ echo "$extracted)"
libtirpc-common:arm64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1+deb11u1)
```